# ReactJS onClick event to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I use `onClick` on an anchor to setState within another component?

**Card.js** with `onClick`

```
import React from 'react'
import PropertyLightbox from '../global/PropertyLightbox'

const Card = (props) => {
    const propertyImages = props.gallery
    return (
        <Property id={props.slug}>
          <a onClick={this.openLightbox} href="javascript:;">Click to open lightbox</a>
          <PropertyLightbox lbImages={propertyImages}/>
        </Property>
    )
}
export default Card
```

**PropertyLightbox.js**  with `setState` `openLightbox`

```
class propertyLightbox extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { currentImage: 0 };
        this.openLightbox = this.openLightbox.bind(this);
    }

    openLightbox(event, obj) {
        this.setState({
            currentImage: obj.index,
            lightboxIsOpen: true,
        });
    }
    render() {
      return (
            <Lightbox images={this.props.propertyImages}
            isOpen={this.state.lightboxIsOpen}
            </Lightbox>
      )
    }
}

propertyLightbox.propTypes = {
    propertyImages: PropTypes.func,
}

export default propertyLightbox
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could

- convert your Card component to a class and give it state: `hasOpenLightBox`
- set `hasOpenLightBox` to `true` in `this.openLightbox`
- give PropertyLightbox that as a prop: `<PropertyLightbox isOpen={this.state.hasOpenLightBox}`
- setState or do whatever you need to do inside PropertyLightbox based in the `isOpen` prop

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to avoid setting the Card component to a class. Cheers again.